# "problem" in tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Another tagging question: Should we include the word "problem" for classical problems?

- [traveling-salesman](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman) vs. [traveling-salesman-problem](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman-problem)
- [shortest-path](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path) vs. [shortest-path-problem](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path-problem)
- [p-median](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-median) vs. [p-median-problem](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-median-problem)

Comment: Larry, I removed the multiple polling-style answers you posted in favor of an open discussion. If you have thoughts on the issue, please please feel free to post it as an answer; but it is generally better to **let everyone have a voice in meta** to express their own opinions rather pre-posting all sides of the conversation yourself. It's not difficult to infer what the community wants from the conversation while allowing for the possibility that there's an issue we have *not* considered. **[Polling is generally not a good substitute for discussion](http://bit.ly/1g0BO6d)**. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I'm sorry about that, I thought this was the preferred way to solicit feedback about questions like this. I posted several others like this; I will go ahead and delete those answers, unless you have beaten me to it.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search on Stack Overflow shows that questions about classical problems are tagged like [traveling-salesman](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman), [vehicle-routing](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-routing), [shortest-path](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path), etc. In order to keep it consistent, I think it's better for us to leave "problem" out of the tag as well.

Comment: You don't need to use code formatting; use `[tag:tagname]` formatting! Also, Stack Overflow is the legal name.

Comment: I edited the answer. Thanks @double-beep.