# Synonymise [vrp] and [vehicle-routing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[vrp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrp) = **v**ehicle **r**outing **p**roblem and the community [has decided](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/80) **not** to allow "-problem" in tags, so I propose these tags to be synonymized with master the [vehicle-routing](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-routing) tag.

Comment: related discussion [here](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/synonymise-tsp-and-traveling-salesman)

Comment: Yeah, it's preferred to post 1 request per post, so they can be managed.