# Should questions related to career in OR be considered as on topic

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we consider questions such as:

**What are the typical responsibilities of an Operation Research Developer?**

**What are good interview questions to ask when hiring an Operation Research Analyst?**

As being on topic?

Even though they are related with the field of OR they are not OR questions per se.

Comment: Related: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/are-questions-about-the-field-of-or-on-topic

Comment: Absldamnlutely.

Comment: See also Physics.Meta.SE: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/905/questions-concerning-a-career-in-research-on-or-off-topic or https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/is-it-relevant-to-ask-questions-regarding-careers-in-physics-and-not-actually-so/7524#7524 where it's a mixed bag.

Answer (score 11):

My personal opinion is that those questions should be considered as on topic.

They could be a tremendous help both for students in the field wanting to know what their future job could look like as for professionals already working and wanting to prepare for interviews.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO career questions, in general, should be on-topic. However:

https://or.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

I think "what are good interview questions to ask when hiring an OR analyst" risks being too open-ended and too widely scoped.