# What is the "People" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There has been [one use](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/357/491) of the [people](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people) tag. It currently has zero watchers.

That one question seems to solicit answers with parent-child pairs that both work(ed) in Operations Research.

**What is this tag for?  When should it be used?**

At the time of this posting, the tag currently has no [usage guidance](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people).

---

Note:  This question is not about the scope or whether the linked [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/357/491) is on topic.  Based on [this discussion](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/491), questions regarding the *field of OR* are considered on topic if (1) they are not too broad, and (2) they are not primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret that tag to refer to questions about to people related to OR. Presumably in the future it could be used to tag questions related to figures in the history of OR, questions about who first developed certain theories, etc. I'll add a tag usage guidance.